# Henry's law p = kx vs m = kp

Tags: aqueous-solution, solutions

What exactly is the difference between the following equations?
$$p = kx \qquad\text{and}\qquad m = kp$$
Is the $k$ in both same, because I have seen same $k$ in textbooks for both equations?

Comment: Both are different Henry's law constants. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry%27s_law

Comment: Henry's law constants also reflect an implicit scale: molality, mole fraction, concentration, etc. (with a given reference state defined as such).